# How to play video file on login page(background) in android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, video, surfaceview, android-videoview

[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI6Si.png) I want to make the same as vine app has.  I tried to implement it  by looking some answers at stackoverflow.com. But I could not. What about a size of video and quality? A size of app will increased? If I will use file that inserted in raw folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of my apps contain a video as background. Placed in res/raw/ with 4,9 MB, 750x1334 Pixel, 20 seconds and H.264, AAC codec.

This of course increases the app size - even if you got minifyEnabled true /  shrinkResources true for building the apk.

Example code (onCreate):

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.background_video);

videoView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.requestFocus();
```

Don't forget to call videoView.pause/start at onPause/onResume

Comment: How did you implement it? Can you share with your source code?

Comment: How much it is increased? 5 mb?

Comment: Yes, app size increased 5 mb. See my edit for a partial example code.